React Native 0.74.5 build failure with MapBox
I am somewhat new to Stack Overflow posting, so if I formatted this poorly please explain how to fix it and I will as soon as able.
I am working on a project that uses Mapbox/maps and I recently upgraded my React Native from 0.71.19 to 0.74.5, but now it no longer loads, giving the same error each time. After a day of testing and googling, I made a test template project to see if it was a configuration/install issue or incompatibility with another package. I have followed the guides found on the repo for installing correctly I believe (again, worked fine before update). So far, no matter what I have done it always ends with the
'Execution failed for task ':rnmapbox_maps:compileDebugKotlin'.
testMapbox@0.0.1 android
react-native run-android

info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
info Installing the app...

Task :rnmapbox_maps:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
49 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 41 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

e: file:///C:/Users/npmye/Documents/testMapbox/node_modules/@rnmapbox/maps/android/src/main/java/com/rnmapbox/rnmbx/components/images/RNMBXImagesManager.kt:212:5 'addView' overrides nothing
e: file:///C:/Users/npmye/Documents/testMapbox/node_modules/@rnmapbox/maps/android/src/main/java/com/rnmapbox/rnmbx/components/images/RNMBXImagesManager.kt:227:5 'removeView' overrides nothing
e: file:///C:/Users/npmye/Documents/testMapbox/node_modules/@rnmapbox/maps/android/src/main/java/com/rnmapbox/rnmbx/components/images/RNMBXImagesManager.kt:236:5 'removeAllViews' overrides nothing
e: file:///C:/Users/npmye/Documents/testMapbox/node_modules/@rnmapbox/maps/android/src/main/java/com/rnmapbox/rnmbx/components/styles/sources/RNMBXTileSourceManager.kt:13:5 'getChildAt' overrides nothing
e: file:///C:/Users/npmye/Documents/testMapbox/node_modules/@rnmapbox/maps/android/src/main/java/com/rnmapbox/rnmbx/components/styles/sources/RNMBXTileSourceManager.kt:17:5 'getChildCount' overrides nothing
e: file:///C:/Users/npmye/Documents/testMapbox/node_modules/@rnmapbox/maps/android/src/main/java/com/rnmapbox/rnmbx/components/styles/sources/RNMBXTileSourceManager.kt:21:5 'addView' overrides nothing
e: file:///C:/Users/npmye/Documents/testMapbox/node_modules/@rnmapbox/maps/android/src/main/java/com/rnmapbox/rnmbx/components/styles/sources/RNMBXTileSourceManager.kt:25:5 'removeViewAt' overrides nothing
e: file:///C:/Users/npmye/Documents/testMapbox/node_modules/@rnmapbox/maps/android/src/main/rn-compat/rn75/com/rnmapbox/rnmbx/rncompat/ResourceDrawableIdHelper.kt:5:37 Unresolved reference: Companion

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':rnmapbox_maps:compileDebugKotlin'.
A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
Compilation error. See log for more details

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 12s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

I am running Node.js v20.17.0
package.json:
"@rnmapbox/maps": "^10.1.30",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.74.5"

android/build.gradle ext:
buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
minSdkVersion = 23
compileSdkVersion = 34
targetSdkVersion = 34
ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
kotlinVersion = "1.9.22"
RNMapboxMapsImpl = "mapbox"

To Reproduce:

Create test project with RN 0.74.5
npm install @rnmapbox/maps
Follow instructions here: https://rnmapbox.github.io/docs/install?configure-module=android&rebuild=android
npm run android --reset-cache

I did try running this template project with the barebones RN template for 0.74.5, which did load without rnmapbox installed, and I tried reverting back to @rnmapbox/maps@10.1.8 (what I used before updating), but it still didn't work. I could revert back to an earlier version of RN or even back to 0.71.19 if necessary, but I am hoping to avoid that, as I am having trouble setting up projects for most RN versions (a whole separate issue I hope)

The problem is you are using unsupported react-native and mapbox versions.

Downgrade react-native to 0.74.2
Downgrade @rnmapbox/maps to ^10.1.27

Make sure you are using the right version by going into the node_module into each packages. Directly updating the version in package.json doesn't work for me. I had to uninstall and reinstall it with the specific versions in the terminal.

If you are using java 22, downgrade it to java 21 to be compatible with the compileKotlin version.


This doesn't seem to work completely. I tried those versions on both Java 21 and Java 17 but on both I was still getting errors. At least on Java 17 they were new errors, talking about files missing a bunch of dependencies, but still not building. There may be something wrong with my environment, as I was struggling to install 0.74.2 manually after uninstalling, so probably in a couple weeks Ill take another crack at it after looking at that.
